# Argparse Reopening file.

Tags: python, io, argparse

I'm using the argparse module and I have a log file which is continuously appended to. I want to open args.file, do something with the content, then close it and opening it again after some time.

An example piece of code:

```
import argparse
import time
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file',type=file)
args = parser.parse_args()

for _ in range(3):
    data = args.file.read()
    print data
    time.sleep(3)
```

Note that args.file.seek(0) is no solution here. I can close the file with args.file.close() but how to open it again?

I can make the filename-argument just a normal string of the filename but i would like to know a solution keeping the argumenttype as a filename.

Comment: I think using the string type and opening the file each time is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parser.add_argument('file',type=file)
```

does not mean, `the argument is to be a file`.  It means

```
value = file(astring)
args.file = value
```

The `type` parameter is a function that operates on a string.  In Python3 `file` has been removed; the equivalent would be:

```
parser.add_argument('file',type=open)
```

There is a `argparse.FileType` class than can be used to open a file with a defined mode; it also recognizes the `-` value.  This can be useful in small scripts that take an input and output, and do little else.  But generally it is better to open the file yourself, preferably in a `with` context so ensure it is closed when no longer used.

```
parser.add_argument('file_name')
args = parser.parse_args()

for _ in range(3):
    with open(args.file_name) as f:
        data = f.read()
    print data
    time.sleep(3)
```

What `Filetype` does do for you is give a 'nice' argparse error message if the file can't be opened.  For example if the name was mistyped in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

you can open it again using

```
args.file = open(args.file.name)
```